# How to access variable from other javascript file to load state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am trying to load data from another javascript file to use as a list of customers in my react project.
Here is the file with the data I am trying to load:

```
var customers = [
  {
    "phone": "(613)555-0125",
    "province":"ON",
    "city":"Ottawa",
    "customer_info":{
      "last_delivery_date":null,
      "orders_this_month":0,
      "buyer_average_order":0.0,
    },
    "country":"Canada",
    "business_name":"Cole's Cappuccino",
    "id": 1,
    "catalog": {
      "item1": "americano",
      "item2": "espresso",
      "item3": "frappuccino"
    }
  },
  {
    "phone": "(403)980-8217",
    "province":"ON",
    "city":"Waterloo",
    "customer_info":{
      "last_delivery_date":"2018-04-30T12:00:00-00:00",
      "orders_this_month":1,
      "buyer_average_order":5.0,
    },
    "country":"Canada",
    "business_name":"Jen's Jello",
    "id":1,
    "catalog": {
      "item1": "raspberry",
      "item2": "green apple",
      "item3": "blueberry",
      "item4": "grape",
      "item5": "orange"
    }
  }
]

var APICall = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, customers);
});
```

And here is how I am trying to load it in my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Customers from './Components/Customers';
import './App.css';
import './util.js';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
        APICall.then(function(result){
            this.setState(result);
        });
    }


    render() {
            return (
            <div className="customer-container">  
                <li className="title">MY CUSTOMERS</li>
                <Customers customers={this.state.customers} onDelete={this.handleDeleteCustomer.bind(this)}/>
            </div>  
            );
        }
    }

export default App;
```

I get the error of "APICall is not defined". Am I going about this the wrong way? I thought you could access any global variable in files that are imported.

Comment: You can only access on import what was exported in the exported file

Comment: You need to export the function, data etc (eg APICall). Please have a look at the link attached: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: do you use webpack? and what is the first file name?

Comment: I fixed the problem using @AfshinGhazi's comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to export APICall and move the `componentWillMount` code to `componentDidMount` in App.js and setState to customers

APICall.js

```
var APICall = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, customers);
});
export default APICall
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Customers from './Components/Customers';
import './App.css';
import './util.js';

class App extends Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {}
}

componentDidMount(){//change componentWillMount to componentDidMount
    const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
    APICall.then(function(result){
        this.setState({customers: result});
    });
}


render() {
        return (
        <div className="customer-container">  
            <li className="title">MY CUSTOMERS</li>
            <Customers customers={this.state.customers} onDelete={this.handleDeleteCustomer.bind(this)}/>
        </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Hope this will help